# How to find a nested node in a Kendo tree view where data is 'lazely' served through a web-api

Tags: kendo-ui

I know the exact route to find a nested node in a Kendo tree view. So I wish to expand all nodes along this route to go and get there.
I know how to find a node and make Kendo expand that node.

My Treeview uses a web-api for its data and all works well.  The schema is defined as follows:

```
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "CodeList",
                    hasChildren: "HasKids"
                }
            }
```

What I want to achieve is for the tree to expand automatically to a nested level.
Say I know the path to get to a node is 'Level1CodeA|Level2CodeA|Level3CodeA' so first I wish to find the code 'Level1CodeA' which I can do.
I then wish to expand this node (internally it retrieves the data under this node and it expands ok) after which I want to find 'Level2CodeA', repeat the process so also find and then select Level3CodeA.

How would I go about this?  I was looking for an 'AfterExpanded' event that I could use to start the next search and expand operation but I can't find any event I can use.  I tried the 'change' event on my datasource but this is fired many times and I can't seem to narrow it down to the correct item..

Many thanks.

EDIT: more code

```
<script id="treeII-template" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
    <img id="explorerItemImg" src="#: item.Image #" />
    <span id="explorerItemCode">#: item.Code #</span> - 
    <span id="explorerItemFullName">#: item.FullName #</span>
    # if (item.Level < (item.Levels - 1)) { #
        [<span id="explorerItemLCount">#: item.LCount #</span>]
    # } #
    # if (item.HasKids) { #
        [<span id="explorerItemPCount">#: item.PCount #</span>]
    # } #

</script>
```

The code to create the HierarchicalDataSource and assigning this to the treeview:

```
    // -----------------
    // set the datasource for the bottom explorer...
    // -----------------
    var loadDataForExplorerGroup = function (context, groupid, groupsequence) {

        // hang on to this context/groupid
        sessionStorage.setItem(context + "_explorer_groupId", groupid);
        sessionStorage.setItem(context + "_explorer_groupSequence", groupsequence);

        // define the datasource and attach it to the explorer-tree
        explorerGroupData = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/api/explorerapi/GetExplorerData?",
                    data: {
                        context: "portfolio",
                        groupid: groupid,
                        groupsequence: groupsequence,
                        userid: sessionStorage.getItem("symUserID")
                    }
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "CodeList",
                    hasChildren: "HasKids"
                }
            }
        });

        // simply assign the data source again to the tree
        $("#idExplBottomTree").data("kendoTreeView").setDataSource(explorerGroupData);

    };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That `AfterExpanded` event might be [`dataBound`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#databound). What I would propose is given the following `TreeView` definition:

```
var tree = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource   : data,
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataBound    : function (e) {
        treeNavigateNext();
    }
}).data("kendoTreeView");
```

I've added `dataBound` handler that invokes `treeNavigate` defined as:

```
function treeNavigateNext() {
    if (search.length > 0) {
        var first = tree.findByText(search[0]);
        if (first) {
            search.shift();
            tree.expand(first);
        }
    }
}
```

Where `search` is an array containing `dataTextField` of each node that we want to navigate.

Example:

```
search = [];
search.push("t_3");
search.push("t_32");
search.push("t_321");
search.push("t_3214");
```

Defines that we want to `expand` a node which text is `t_3`, then `t_32`, next `t_321` and finally `t_3214`.

So `treeNavigateNext` checks that there is still something pending (`search.length > 0`) and if so, find the element by its `text` (`var first = tree.findByText(search[0]);`), removes the element from `search` (`search.shift();`) and finally `expand` the node (`tree.expand(first)`). This causes the next level to be loaded and when received `dataBound` event is triggered and I will go to the next level.

See it running [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/CFWGd/)

**EDIT:** If instead of searching by text you prefer to navigate by `id` then add to `search` array the `id` of the different nodes and use the following `treeNavigateNext` function instead:

```
function treeNavigateNext() {
    if (search.length > 0) {
        var first = tree.dataSource.get(search[0]);
        if (first) {
            search.shift();
            var elem = tree.findByUid(first.uid);
            tree.expand(elem);
        } 
    }
}
```

New running example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/CFWGd/2/)

Comment: That looks brilliant!  Many thanks for that - however, I am using a template to show some properties of the objects that have come back. So finding the node by text doesn't work - how would I go about finding them?

Comment: Added more code:  so the field 'CodeList' is the important one and is NOT shown in the node...  It is unique (which is why I can use it for the id).

Comment: What about searching for the `id` it is pretty easy to modify the example, would that work for you?

Comment: perfect!  How would I do this?

Comment: 10/10 for your answer and help!  Many thanks - working like a treat!

Comment: Actually there is a non documented feature that you might want to _fix_ that if the node is already loaded you actually don't need to specify it into the path since the function is able to expand any already loaded node. Ex: from my JSFiddle example you might say to load `3`, `31`, `312`, `3124`, `33`, `334`, `4`, `41`... From `3124` you can go to `33` since `3` was already expanded and hence `33` is already in the tree, same for the sub-sequence `4`, `41` after `334`.

Comment: There seems to be a problem in the Edit part (search by id) tree.dataSource.get() will only work if LoadOnDemand is false. then it is not lazy loading anymore.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid using a global `search` variable?